# MVC Action Method timing out resulting Error 524

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, iis-8

I am experiencing a peculiar issue with ASP.NET MVC Routing. MVC Action Method times out every time, this happens only on the specific server, while testing the same configuration in other servers it works, the controller has many other action methods which is working fine without issues, whereas this specific MVC Action Method is timing out with Error 524

Below the URL where it fails

```
http://www.126news.com/Publication/AstroStories
```

Below URL where it works fine

```
http://live.makemypublication.com/Publication/AstroStories
```

Below is RouteConfig

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allhtml}", new { allhtml = @".*\.html(/.*)?" });
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Publish/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Views/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allrss}", new { allrss = @".*\.rss(/.*)?" });
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AstroStories",
            url: "Publication/AstroStories",
            defaults: new { controller = "Publication", action = "AstroStories" }
            );
```

Below is the HTTP trace from inetpub/logs/LogFile

```
2019-03-10 00:12:02 172.31.17.122 GET /Publication/AstroStories - 80 - 141.101.107.97 Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+7.1.2;+vivo+1611+Build/N2G47H;+wv)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0+Chrome/72.0.3626.121+Mobile+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 64 240187
```

Below is the HTTP trace from server where it works fine

```
2019-03-10 18:10:42 172.31.21.103 GET /Publication/AstroStories - 80 - 172.68.167.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/72.0.3626.121+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 805
```

Please note, the server where it worked has responded in **805** milliseconds whereas in the server where it times out has responded in **240187**

It is strange that there is not too much of load on these two servers running on EC2 micro instance, not sure why the other server the request always fails with Error 524 which is the CloudFlare error if the origin server is not responded within 100 seconds. My gut says that when other Action methods on this very same server able to respond quickly why only this method, in this controller method only a few lines of code which reads RSS & returns back the json

Below its code

```
public ActionResult AstroStories()
{
    try
    {
        //var posts = Enumerable.Empty<FeedItem>();
        var rssFeed = XDocument.Load(@"http://www.126news.com/Publish/astrology.xml");
        if (rssFeed != null)
        {
            var posts = from item in rssFeed.Descendants("item")
                        select new FeedItem
                        {
                            title = item.Element("title").Value,
                            image = item.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value,
                            pubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value,
                            content = item.Element("description").Value
                        };
            return Json(posts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("ERROR: NOT FOUND");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace(eX, true);
        // Get the top stack frame
        var frame = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1);
        // Get the line number from the stack frame
        var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

        return Json(string.Format("ERROR: {0} LINE {1}", eX.Message, line), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I also experienced other issues, from this EC2 instance I am not able to connect to internet, I have checked outbound rules  which exists with default setting 0-65535 ports open, searching on the net for this solution since few days but no luck, I am ending up creating a new EC2 instance & deploy this application, not so feasible but is ok for me,

**UPDATE**
Issue resolved after restarting aws instance

Comment: Is it able to load the xml feed? My first thought would be it could be hung up on the domain resolution and never filling.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick xml is not so big, I would confirm that however, doman resolution is not an issue as could see the request in HTTP log and also other controller methods getting invoked without any issue, as it showed in the log is a time out issue,